# Calculating the PDF of sum of 2 exponential random variables

Tags: probability

I have $ X_1, X_2 \stackrel{i.i.d.}{\sim} \mathrm{Exponential(\mu)}$, and their sum as a new random variabvle $ Y = X_1 + X_2 $. In order to calculate the PDF of Y,

\begin{align}
\Pr[Y=y] &= \Pr[X_1=a,X_2=y-a] \\
&= \Pr[X_1 = a] \Pr[X_2 = y-a] \\
&= (\mu e^{-\mu a} )(\mu e^{-\mu (y-a) }) \\
&= \mu^2 e^{-\mu y}
\end{align}

However, when I integrate $ \mu^2 e^{-\mu y} $ with respect to $y$, with $y>0$ the area under the curve exceeds 1. Is there an error in finding Y's PDF?

Comment: Probability of a continuous variable taking a particular value is always zero. You should replace the probabilities with probability densities (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having calculated the probability for a *particular* $a$, you now need to integrate the result over *all possible values* of $a$ – between $0$ and $y$. This gives $\mu^2ye^{-\mu y}$, which does integrate to $1$ (it is a gamma distribution).

Comment: Makes sense! I was calculating $ \Pr[Y = y | X_1 = a] $, not $ \Pr[Y = y] $